# access to variable outside of loop javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I have this loop and i want to access to username outside of loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.props.tourists.length; i++) {
  var username = (this.props.tourists[i].id == this.props.chat.sender) ? this.props.tourists[i].nom : ""
  console.log(username, "userName")
}
```

how to do that ?

Comment: variables declared using `var` are hoisted. Its available

Comment: Do you mean that you have `username` outside the loop and want to access that within the loop, or you want to use the `username` variable defined inside the loop outside of it?

Comment: @VLAZ i want to use the username variable defined inside the loop outside of it

Comment: Then you should be able to. `var` does not exist in block scope, it will be accessible outside the `for` loop and after the loop finishes, it will have the last value assigned to it.

Comment: @Rajesh outside of the loop username is empty

Comment: @chmariem That is because, your condition is validated and sets `username` but then in next iteration, its falsey setting it again to `""`. Try using `array.find` or `array.filter`

Answer (score 0):

You can find username without for:

```
    const username = (this.props.tourists.find(t=>t.id === this.props.chat.sender) || {}).nom
    console.log('username=', username)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do like this

```
let username = ''
for (var i = 0; i < this.props.tourists.length; i++) {
  username = (this.props.tourists[i].id == this.props.chat.sender)? this.props.tourists[i].nom : ""
  console.log(username, "userName")
}
// Can access username
```

And you can access username outside for

Comment: variable declared using `var` will be hoisted. So your changes does nothing

Comment: Never seen such weird syntax `let or var username = ""`  and you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: Actually i want to describe use let username = ''